# Slack Slash Command Plugin For Jenkins

Tags: java

I want to write a `Jenkins Plugin` in Java that trigger a new build when a slash command is typed in `Slack`. When this appen, an HTTP POST request is sent at Jenkins URL.

I know that i should extend the Trigger Extension Point and define an inner static class that extends the corresponding descriptor to show this option in the Job Configuration page.

So, I have some questions:

1. How I can listen and manage the requests made by `Slack`? What are the classes that do this?
2. How I can run my plugin when this trigger option is checked and stop the execution when this option is not active?
3. There are similar plugins?

Comment: You don't need an plugin for this, jenkins provides a trigger to start builds from external (e.g. scripts). Just set the checkbox at the job configuration page.

Comment: Hi Erik, I know this. My goal is to define a slash command (e.g. /jenkins operation JobName) in Slack and create a plugin that receive the message send from Slack, parse the message to obtain the operation to be performed and start a the operation. Operation can be: build, maven test, ant test...

Answer (score 0):

I created a small middleware component to accomplish this. It's written in NodeJS, and works pretty well.

Our Jenkins jobs are separated into environments and regions, but with the slash command you can make it deploy from a specific branch (with parameters) and to any environment (job).

https://github.com/victorbello/jenkins-trigger

Hope it helps.